# Fade in Background Image Only after Loading Fully

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to a load a big image background... Even though I am using `.load` the the image just loads normally and not having a smooth fadeIn after loading. Here's my code.

```
$(function(){
    var bgimage = new Image();      
    bgimage.src="http://placeimg.com/760/460/tech";       

    $(bgimage).load(function(){
        $(".feature").css("background-image","url("+$(this).attr("src")+")").fadeIn(slow);                  
    });
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/nud2bfb1/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this : You need to hide image first and then use `fadeIn()`, also `fadeIn(slow)` must be `fadeIn("slow")` i.e. slow in quotes

```
$(function(){
    var bgimage = new Image();      
    bgimage.src="http://placeimg.com/760/460/tech";       
    $(".feature").hide();     
    $(bgimage).load(function(){
        $(".feature").css("background-image","url("+$(this).attr("src")+")").fadeIn(2000); 
     }); 
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nud2bfb1/4/)**

Comment: There is a flicker happening due to the `.hide` anyway to fix that

Comment: You can hide `$(".feature")` before load and use miliseconds for fadeIn, see this http://jsfiddle.net/nud2bfb1/4/

Comment: Nope you are fading in the `.feature` the image loads normally inside it... slow down your internet to see. I want the image to fade in after fully loaded

Comment: How to avoid this http://jsfiddle.net/nud2bfb1/13/ while fading in the image is covering the text for that small interval.

Comment: `.load` is deprecated since version 1.8, but it works equally well with `.on('load', function() { })`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot detect load on background images. You cannot transition / animate background images.

What you and other answers are trying to do is to fade/animate the entire `div` after loading an `img` element. This doesn't work every time flawlessly. Because, this IMO is disruptive because either the entire `div` (along with its content) has to be kept hidden while the image is loading, or you hide the `div` and then attempt to fade it. This will give you flicker as the `div` is hidden abruptly before the fade.

What I would suggest is that you use a dummy `img` element as you are already doing, but position it absolute (in relation to `div`) with the same size and negative `z-index`. This way, the `div` and its content can be visible while the image is loading. Once loaded, you fade the dummy `img` in (behind the `div`), then assign the `background-image` and then remove the dummy `img`.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/q7cvn2nd/***

***See this snippet:***

```js
var $img = $("<img />");

$img.load(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $('.feature').css('background-image', 'url(http://lorempixel.com/240/240)');
        $(this).remove(); 
    });   
});

$img.addClass("dummy");
$img.attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/240/240');
$(".feature").append($img);
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.feature {
    position: relative;
    width: 240px; height: 240px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 8px; color: #f00; 
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
img.dummy {
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="feature"><h1>This is some text.</h1></div>
```

**Important**: *Do not forget to remove the dummy image.*

Answer (score 0):

Your image is displayed by default. Hide it before fading it in :

```
<div class="feature" style="display:none;"></div>
```

**FIDDLE** : http://jsfiddle.net/nud2bfb1/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var bgimage = new Image();      
    bgimage.src="http://placeimg.com/760/460/tech";       

    $(bgimage).load(function(){
        $(".feature").css("background-image","url("+$(this).attr("src")+")").not(':visible').fadeIn("slow");               
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/nud2bfb1/6/)

Comment: Nope you are fading in the `.feature` the image loads normally inside it... slow down your internet to see

Comment: Thats is what you were doing , fading the .feature !

Comment: I am doing wrong then, please do the correction... want the image to fade in after fully loaded not the `.feature`